# C++: 'cout << pointer << ++pointer' generates a compiler warning

Tags: c++, compiler-warnings, cout

I have a C++ learning demo here:

```
char c = 'M';
short s = 10;
long l = 1002;
char * cptr = &c;
short * sptr = &s;
long * lptr = &l;
cout << "cptr:\t" << static_cast<void*>(cptr) << '\n';
cout << "cptr++:\t" << static_cast<void*>(++cptr) << '\n';
cout << "sptr:\t" << sptr << '\n';
cout << "sptr++:\t" << ++sptr << '\n';
cout << "lptr:\t" << lptr << '\n';
cout << "lptr++:\t" << ++lptr << '\n';

cout << c << '\t' << static_cast<void*>(cptr) << '\t' << static_cast<void*>(++cptr) << '\n';
cout << s << '\t' << sptr << '\t' << ++sptr << '\n';
cout<< l << '\t' << lptr << '\t'<< ++lptr << '\n';
```

The compiler warnings:

[image]

Can anyone explain this to me?  How to fix it?

Comment: I'm not an expert, but I suspect this is likely related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points, if not a duplicate

Comment: Better to paste warning straightly for searching.

Comment: Split the cout statements in several lines to force execution order.

Comment: @Tas can you point out where in that Q/A it covers the code in this question?

Comment: @M.M you're clearly more of an expert here, and I upvoted your answer, but the part in the first answer that talks about the order of evaluation and an object having its value accessed only once in a single statement, and I thought the `printf` code demonstrated this same problem. I may be wrong ofc, but when I saw this question and read through that I assumed it was very related if not the answer, but I didn't attempt to close this only link what I thought might be useful

Comment: Sigh, reopened. The alleged duplicate does not cover this code  , pretty sick of low-effort users hastily closing things because there are a couple of words in common with another question

Answer (score 8):

[Since C++17 the code is correct](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50361284/1505939).

[Prior to C++17](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points) the evaluation of operands of a `<<` chain was unsequenced, so the code caused undefined behaviour.

The compiler warning suggests you are not compiling in C++17 mode. To fix it you could either:

- Compile in C++17 mode, or
- Separate the `<<` chain into multiple `cout <<` statements where there is not `x` and `++x` within the same statement.

---

*Note:* As of now, all versions of g++ seem to be bugged and not implement these sequencing requirements correctly, see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51784836/shift-operands-sequenced-in-c17) for some more examples.   The warnings can be seen as indicating the compiler bug; they are not just bogus warnings.

Comment: Why does with `-std=c++17 -Wall` still show warning? Shouldn't it be suppressed by `-std=c++17`? Or `-Wall` can warn suppressed warning even though it is suppressed by the standard? => [compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/g/JzobCb)

Comment: @sandthorn There is no such thing as "suppressed by the standard". The standard allows any implementation to warn for any code for any reason. The quality of the diagnostics does not affect conformance. That said, if a warning is giving out incorrect information it may be worth reporting as a bug. The implementors do want to provide good diagnostics.

Comment: @hvd It turns out that GCC doesn't warn, even with `std=c++11`, unless with `-Wall`. While clang warns "no matter what". => [compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/g/qkgCyE)

Comment: agree that a bug should be reported for clang 6 and gcc 8.1 -Wall bogus warnings

Answer (score 1):

You re having undefined behavior in lines `18, 19, 20`. Cause of the result of executing the line will be different depending on whether `ptr` or `++ptr` is evaluated first.

Comment: While I agree this is probably the right answer, your answer could be improved by explaining why it's not guaranteed that one will be evaluated before the other, is this a compiler thing or dictated by the standard, and what can be done to fix it?

Comment: So how to fix it?

Comment: @K.F It turns out that GCC doesn't warn, even with `std=c++11`, unless with `-Wall`. While clang warns "no matter what". => [compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/g/qkgCyE) So, in case of clang, you must provide option `-Wunsequenced` to suppress it.

Comment: @sandthorn In case of clang, it seems the -Wunsequenced option cannot suppress the warning. Have you tried that?

Comment: @K.F My bad and decency of time-limited comment fixing policy. It should be `-Wno-unsequenced`. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>According to C++ Standard Draft Paper [N4762](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/blob/master/papers/n4762.pdf) (2018-07-07) on page 68 in section *§ 6.8.1/10*</strike>

( or *[intro.execution]/10* on *eel.is* website [**here**](http://eel.is/c++draft/intro.execution#10) )

> Except where noted, evaluations of operands of individual operators and of subexpressions of individual expressions are unsequenced.

---

For statement

```
cout << c << '\t' << static_cast<void*>(cptr) << '\t' << static_cast<void*>(++cptr) << '\n';
```

that means c++ compiler can **not** guarantee that `static_cast<void*>(cptr)` will be evaluated before `++cptr` on the right because they are all operands on the **same** statement.

So you can force their sequential order of execution simply by ordering them in ordered and separated statements.

For example :

```
cout << c << '\t' << static_cast<void*>(cptr) << '\t'; cout << static_cast<void*>(++cptr) << '\n';
```

[[ compiler explorer ]](https://godbolt.org/g/ZtSfTP)

---

### Update

As M.M's answer states that c++17 now guarantees operand evaluation sequence of `<<`

It turns out that GCC 8.1 doesn't warn, even with `std=c++11`, unless with `-Wall` and always warns with `-Wall`

While clang 6.0 warns "no matter what".

[[ compiler explorer ]](https://godbolt.org/g/qkgCyE)

So, as well as `-std=c++17`, you must *also* provide option `-Wno-unsequenced` to suppress it :

- if you are on clang 6.0
- if you are on gcc 8.1 with `-Wall`

Comment: @M.M I added "also" but you may edit mine if still ambiguous. Or do you suggest that both compiler still not guarantee `<<` operand evaluation sequence with `-std=c++17` because the warning are still there?

Comment: @M.M I changed wording from "other than" to "as well as"