# structure and functions in C++

Tags: c++, struct

Can someone explain why this code gives the output 10?  When I try to analyse it my logic gives as result 11.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std; 
class A { 
public:     
    A() { a.a = a.b = 1; }   
    struct { int a,b; } a;  
    int b(void); 
};

int A::b(void) { 
    int x=a.a;
    a.a=a.b;
    a.b=x; 
    return x; 
};

int main(void) {     
    A a;
    a.a.a = 0;
    a.b();
    cout << a.b() << a.a.b << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: Perhaps read about [Sequence Points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ It does contain a MCVE.

Comment: @M.M Well, that's a stock comment, including the possibility the OP missed that. I still see no debugging effort s in the question though.

Comment: I would rather see comments that address the specific question, and not stock comments.  Also I doubt how useful a debugger is here; it would not give any explanation as to why that order occurred (and it might be difficult to pick up from the debugger when the `a.a.b` was evaluated relative to `a.b()`)

Comment: I step through my code line-by-line before asking on Stack Overflow!!!, I did analyse it and my logic result was different from the debugger, for that reason I asked to the community... thanks

Answer (score 2):

In the `cout` line, `a.b()` could either be called before or after `a.a.b` is evaluated.   Beginners sometimes assume left-to-right evaluation in this sort of code but actually that is not a rule of C++.

Those two different possibilities would explain your `10` and `11`. To avoid ambiguity you could write:

```
cout << a.b();
cout << a.a.b << endl;
```

(assuming that order was your intent).

Note: C++17 [may change this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38501587/what-are-the-evaluation-order-guarantees-introduced-by-c17) and define left-right evaluation order for this code.

Answer (score 0):

Other than using a debugger, you can also use `cout` statements to help keep track of when things are called.

To kind of help myself out tracing your program I fixed a bit of the indentation and added comments as to when things are happening:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std; 
class A {
public:
    A() {
        a.a = a.b = 1;
    }
    struct {
        int a,b;
    } a;
    int b(void); 
};

int A::b(void) {
    cout << "Within A::b()" << endl;
    // swap a.a, a.b
    int x=a.a;
    a.a=a.b;
    a.b=x;

    cout << "a.a.a = " << a.a << " a.a.b: " << a.b << endl;

    return x;
};

int main(void) {
    // sets a.a.a = 1, a.a.b = 1
    A a;
    // sets a.a.a = 0, a.a.b = 1
    a.a.a = 0;
    // a.a.a = 1, a.a.b = 0
    a.b();
    // check output here
    cout << a.b() << a.a.b << endl;
    return 0; 
}
```

The above program results with the following output on http://cpp.sh/ :

```
Within A::b()
a.a.a = 1 a.a.b: 0
Within A::b()
a.a.a = 0 a.a.b: 1
10
```

In all, it depends on whether or not a.b() or a.a.b is resolved first when you call `cout`. In this case, operator precedence is undefined due to how `cout` works. [This stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5214611/unexpected-order-of-evaluation-compiler-bug/5214681#5214681) has some good info on this.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time and adding your comments to the code... I really appreciate it and it was very helpful... thanks Joe