# Simple code giving unexpected output in c++

Tags: c++, reference, cout, operator-precedence, decrement

Does it have something to do with order of execution of cout statement?

**Code:**

```
int main() {

int x=80;
int &y=x;
cout<<x<<" "<<(--y)<<endl;
return 0;
}
```

**Output:** `79 79`

Answer (score 3):

> Does it have something to do with order of execution of cout
>   statement?

This has everything to do with the [order of evaluation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order). Until c++17 your example would exhibit undefined behaviour:

> If a side effect on a scalar object is unsequenced relative to a value
>   computation using the value of the same scalar object, the behavior is
>   undefined.

Since c++17 the behaviour is defined and the correct output in this case is

```
80 79
```

Answer (score 2):

It's undefined behavior, meaning anything could happen.

For more information see: [Unexpected order of evaluation (compiler bug?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5214611/unexpected-order-of-evaluation-compiler-bug/5214681#5214681)