# Confused Regarding Incrementing Pointer with ++

Tags: c++, pointers, syntax, c++17

so I am a beginner pretty much but I stumbled on something confusing to me.

```
int* p = new int[3];
//Now I want to increment the Pointer and add value 10 there.
int* n = new int[3];


std::cout << n  << std::endl;

*n++=10; 

std::cout << n << " :: " <<  *n << std::endl; 

return 0;
```

However, what gets printed on the second std::cout @ * n is zero and not the expected 10. The pointer address seem to have increased by 4 bytes successfully but not the value. What am I doing wrong? Doing the same with *n+1 = 10; works like intended.

```
    int main()
{
    int* n = new int[3];
    
    
    std::cout << n  << std::endl;
    
    *(n+1)=10; 
    
    std::cout << n << " :: " <<  *(n+1) << std::endl; 

    return 0;
}
```

I also noticed that outputting following

```
int main()
{
    int* n = new int[3];
    
    
    std::cout << n <<"::"<< n++ ;
}
```

now on the n++ print, I would expect the hex value to have increased by 4, however it actually decreased by 4. Why is that? I expected it to be 4 larger than n but n++ is 4 smaller. If i do n-- the address seems to get larger? I am really confused

Comment: Are you sure you compile with C++17? In C++17, `std::cout << n <<"::"<< n++;` should print twice the same value, whereas it is unspecified or UB before.

Comment: `*n++=10;` first adds 10 to `*n`, then increments `n` (same as `*n+=10; n+=1;`). If you want the opposite order, try `*++n=10;` (Better yet, don't do such things at all, they are confusing and error-prone).

Comment: _@ * n_? Seriously?

Comment: the problem in your code is the difference between `n++` and `++n`, `n++` simply first yield the **n** value, then increase it, so you are assigning 10 to `n[0]`, then `++` operator after `n` increase it, so when you print `*n` you are printing n[1] to console but you changed `n[0]`, you should use `++n` because it first increase the pointer then use it.

Comment: also in last question the rule of 'n++' and '++n' is still the same, so you should the same value twice i think, because the real pointer increment happens after printing `n++` on console, so you will see the same hex value

Answer (score 0):

```
*n++ = 10;
```

is the same as

```
*n = 10; n += 1;
```

So, in fact you are setting the first element of the array to `10`, then increment `n` to point to the second element of the array. Then

```
std::cout << n << " :: " <<  *n << std::endl;
```

will print address and value of the *second* element of the array. Since you never assigned anything to it it's value is indeterminate and technically undefined behavior occurs.

---

The last piece of code is more interesting:

```
std::cout << n <<"::"<< n++ ;
```

it's undefined behavior before C++17. And will print the same value twice with C++17 or later. It's all about sequence points.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points) for a general overview and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5214611/unexpected-order-of-evaluation-compiler-bug) is almost a duplicate for it.

Comment: There is nothing to do with sequence points in `std::cout << n <<"::"<< n++;`  which you provided; some details are available under the second link you provided.